# Can't click on different categories cyclically to reach the target page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to click on the several categories to reach the target page of a website. My below script can do the same once but when it comes to repeat the process, it throws `stale element` error. How can i make it successful?

This is my try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.courts.com.sg/"

def get_information(driver,mlink):
    driver.get(mlink)
    #the following line click on the menu
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span.nav-toggle'))).click()
    # It now clicks on the individual categories
    for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#menu-top1535320854159022796-menu .nav-anchor .opener'))):
        item.click()
        # It then click on the sub-categories
        for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.nav-dropdown h3 a'))):
            link.click()
            # Then on the target items
            for ilink in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'li.show a')))[1:]:
                ilink.click()
                #this is where the scripts throws "stale element error" never gets back to repeat the process


if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_information(driver,url)
    finally:  
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: give a sleep of 1-2 seconds in for loop before ilink.click() and try.

Comment: I tried your suggested approach in the first place but that didn't work out @Naveen Kumar R B. Still threw the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `stale element` because menu opens when you hover on it and disappears when do some clicks inside your loops.
Solution 1 - get all sub menu links without open menu:

```
def get_information(driver,mlink):
    driver.get(mlink)
    submenu_links = []
    submenus = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.submenu li a')))
    for submenu in submenus:
        submenu_links.append(submenu.get_attribute("href"))

    for link in submenu_links
        driver.get(link)
```

Solution 2 - If you have to open menu:

```
def get_information(driver,mlink):
    driver.get(mlink)
    #the following line click on the menu, what is this and why?
    #wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span.nav-toggle'))).click()
    # It now clicks on the individual categories

    menus = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.navigation li.nav-item')))
    for menu in menus:

        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).perform()

        submenu_links = []
        submenus = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.submenu li a')))
        for submenu in submenus:
            submenu_links.append(submenu.get_attribute("href"))

        for link in submenu_links
            driver.get(link)
```

Comment: Your second solution threw the `stale element` error as well. I put this `submenu_links = []` line just after `driver.get(mlink)` for the script to work. Btw, the error thrown when it hits the line `submenu_links.append(submenu.get_attribute("href"))` for the second time.

Comment: Check cond in answer again. If will not work, use first solution, it's better and faster

Answer (score 1):

Below is a different approach to solve the problem...(I don't link CSS selectors :))

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = []
url = "https://www.courts.com.sg/"
def get_information(driver,mlink):
    driver.get(mlink)
    sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    uls = soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'nav-mobile'})
    for li in uls[0].find_all('li', {'class': 'nav-item'}):
        submenu = li.find_all('div', {'class':'nav-dropdown'})
        uls = submenu[0].find_all('ul')
        for ul in uls:
            all_li = ul.find_all('li')
            for i in range(1,len(all_li)):
                a = all_li[i].find_all('a')
                print(a)
                a = 'https://www.courts.com.sg' + a[0].get('href')
                url_list.append(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/sarthak_negi_/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_information(driver,url)
    finally:  
        driver.quit()
```

url_list contains all the links of the dropdown options..do a get on them and you can access that page. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Your suggested approach worked beautifully but i don't wish to use BeautifulSoup in this case. Provided plus one. Thanks.